# Array operation not working in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to perform a calculation in Mathematica 9.0. It is using NSum and works just fine when I use a single value of 't'. The problem is I would like to the calculation for an array of 't'. So I simply changed `t = 0.3` to `t = {0.3, 0.4}` for example. It will now not evaluate with the reason `Summand *my equation* is not numerical at point k = 0`.

I dont quite understand why though, because it will work if I try a value of `0.3` or `0.4` separately. But I would like to do it over an array of values.

My function is

`NSum[(-1)^k/k!*(t/0.6)^(0.6*k + 1), {k, 0, 5000},WorkingPrecision -> 10, NSumTerms -> 5000]`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Table` :-

```
Table[NSum[(-1)^k/k!*(t/0.6)^(0.6*k + 1), {k, 0, 5000}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 10, NSumTerms -> 5000], {t, {0.3, 0.4}}]
```

> {0.26, 0.30}

Answer (score 1):

Another way..

```
t={.3, .4}
Function[t, 
      NSum[(-1)^k/k!*(t/0.6)^(0.6*k + 1), {k, 0, 5000}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 10, NSumTerms -> 5000], {Listable}][t]


{0.26, 0.30}
```

This has the advantage of working the same whether t is a list or a single value..